# How can I view the list of all users I have exchanged at least one direct message in Slack?

Tags: slack

How can I view the list of all users I have exchanged at least one direct message in Slack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can press on <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> or click on:

[image]

This will list all direct messages sorted by descending time of last message:

[image]